# Meteor JS - Exception from sub id (id that does not exist)

Tags: javascript, meteor, publish-subscribe

> I20150615-07:11:17.859(9)? Exception from sub draftsList id
>   GghnkQkdjNSTyHuQs Error: Match error: Expected object, got undefined
>   I20150615-07:11:17.859(9)?     at checkSubtree
>   (packages/check/match.js:275:1) I20150615-07:11:17.859(9)?     at
>   check (packages/check/match.js:32:1) I20150615-07:11:17.859(9)?     at
>   [object Object].Meteor.publish.Meteor.users.find.userId [as _handler]
>   (app/server/publications.js:44:3) I20150615-07:11:17.859(9)?     at
>   maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1617:1)
>   I20150615-07:11:17.859(9)?     at [object Object]._.extend._runHandler
>   (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:950:1) I20150615-07:11:17.859(9)?
>   at [object Object]._.extend._startSubscription
>   (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:769:1) I20150615-07:11:17.859(9)?
>   at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.sub
>   (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:582:1) I20150615-07:11:17.859(9)?
>   at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546:1 I20150615-07:11:17.860(9)?
>   Sanitized and reported to the client as: Match failed [400]

I am working on a meteor project and I'm getting this weird error on my terminal.

The problem is when it says `Exception from sub draftsList id GghnkQkdjNSTyHuQs Error: Match error: Expected object, got undefined`, the id always changes on page refresh, and are not in my database (nowhere to be seen).

The thing is, everything works find..

Here is my `publication-subscription`

**Publication**

```
Meteor.publish('draftsList', function (options) {   
  check(this.userId, String);
  check(options, {
    limit: Number
  });

  var drafts = Drafts.find({'user._id': this.userId}, options);

  return drafts;
});
```

**Subscription**

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id', {
  name: 'postPage',
  // limit: function () {
  //   return
  // }
  subscriptions: function () {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('singlePost', this.params._id),
      Meteor.subscribe('userStatus'),
      Meteor.subscribe('draftsList'),
      Meteor.subscribe('draftsList', {
        limit: Number(Session.get('draftsLimit'))
      }),
      Meteor.subscribe('comments', {
          postId: this.params._id
        }, {
          limit: Number(Session.get('commentLimit'))
      }),
      Meteor.subscribe('answers', {
          postId: this.params._id
        }, {
          limit: Number(Session.get('answerLimit'))
      })
    ];
  },
  data: function() {
    return Posts.findOne({_id:this.params._id});
   },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are subscribing to `draftsList` twice in your route. The first subscription is without any parameters, which will make `options` be `undefined` instead of an object. Just remove the first subscription and the problem should go away.

Also note that using `check` for `this.userId` may work in this case but could cause problems if you were using `waitOn` in your route. The generally accepted pattern is to return `[]` or `this.ready()` when `this.userId` is `undefined` in a publisher which requires an authenticated client.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your `check` against `this.userId` in your publication, you don't need to check this property validity since Meteor already does it for you.

```
Meteor.publish('draftsList', function (options) {   
  check(options, {
    limit: Number
  });
  var drafts = Drafts.find(this.userId, options);
  return drafts;
});
```